# Distriqt Facebook ANE won't compile for Android

Tags: facebook, air, air-native-extension, ane, distriqt

I am having trouble compiling the Distriqt Facebook ANE for Android.
It works fine on iOS but not on Android.
The error message is:

> dx tool failed:
>
> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
>   space     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.ExecutionStack.copy(ExecutionStack.java:66)    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.Frame.copy(Frame.java:98)  at
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:786)   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:742)   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:349)    at
>   com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:280)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
>     at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)   at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>
> ADT command line:
>   ...

Tried with AIR18 and AIR 16 (updated dx.jar from distriqt tutorial).
My manifest includes all 3 needed extensions:

```
<extensionID>com.distriqt.Core</extensionID>
<extensionID>com.distriqt.GooglePlayServices</extensionID>
<extensionID>com.distriqt.FacebookAPI</extensionID>
```

Removing GooglePlayServices makes compilation possible but app crashes when initializing the FacebokAPI.

Using AIR16 **without** the updated dx.jar also crashes the app directly at startup. The catlog states the following exception:

> 08-23 14:53:14.793 E/AndroidRuntime(3178): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider
>   in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/air.my.com.zas.lefiner-1.apk]
>
> 08-23 14:53:14.793 E/AndroidRuntime(3178): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider
>   in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/air.my.com.zas.lefiner-1.apk]

Oddly enough the Distriqt GooglePlusANE which uses Core and GooglePlayServices works fine on both platforms. So i strongly assume there is something wrong with the FacebookAPI extension.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are using `Intellij IDEA` increase `Compiler heap size` in `Actionscript` & `Flex` compiler. This fixed the issue for me.